# Are there any properties to get only the language used to display browser UI in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser, frontend

I set 3 languages on [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/), then I set the 2nd language `English` for displaying the Google Chrome UI as shown below:

[image]

Then, I tried to get only the 2nd language `English` used to display the Google Chrome UI because for users, I want to show my website in their languages used to display their browser UI by default and translation when they visit my website but I got the 1st language `French` as shown below:

```html
<script>
console.log(navigator.language); // fr
console.log(navigator.browserLanguage); // undefined
console.log(navigator.systemLanguage); // undefined
console.log(navigator.userLanguage); // undefined
</script>
```

So, are there any properties to get only the 2nd language `English` used to display the Google Chrome UI?

Answer (score 0):

`window.navigator.languages` is an array of the users preferred languages in order of preference. `window.navigator.language` is the language the web browser is using. So to get the 2nd language, you'd use `window.navigator.languages[1]`

EDIT: window.navigator.language may not always match the UI language of the browser (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/language) - This is as close as you will get tho.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to show my website to users in the language used to display their browser UI

This is not possible, and you shouldn't do it anyway. Apart from the existence of browsers without a UI or choosable UI language, your website is to be displayed *inside* a browser, as *content*. For that, the preferred website **content** language is the setting that is relevant - and also it's the only one available to your website. In the huge majority of cases this is the same as the UI language, so it won't make a difference to you, but in the cases where the user explicitly chose to display the browser UI in a different language than the visited websites, you should respect that decision. You're making a website after all, not building a browser extension.

So use [`navigator.language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/language), or for a best match from available languages, the prioritised list of [`navigator.languages`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/languages). There is no way to access the UI language setting.

Comment: Again, their UI language does not matter! Your website should default to the language that the user prefers for *website content*.